# Is $\arg(f(z))$ continuous??

Tags: complex-analysis

Given some $f(z)$ which is bounded by the open ball $B(1,1)$ in the complex plane, is $\arg(f(z))$ continuous? It says it is, but I do not see why. For instance inside the open ball $B(1,1)$ we can have some closed ball $\overline {B(1,0.5)}$ which is defined by the function $0.5e^{iz}$, now if we have $\arg(0.5e^{i0})=\arg(0.5)=2\pi$ and $\arg(0.5e^{i2\pi})=\arg(0.5)=2\pi+2k\pi$, but clearly they are not equal so they are not continuous, and hence $\arg (f(z)) \in B(1,1)$ cannot be continuous?

Am I correct, or am I failing to see something here?

Comment: What can we say is that there is a continuous version of $g(z) = \arg f(z)$, i.e., a function $g$ satisfying $f(z) = |f(z)| \exp(ig(z))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $z\in B(1,1)$, we have $\text{Re}(z)> 0$, hence, the principal value of $\text{arg}(z)$ is strictly between $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$, and there are no jumps.

Explicitly, for $z\in B(1,1)$, if we write $z=x+iy$, we always have $x>0$, hence the principal value of $\text{arg}(z)$ is given by
$$\text{arg}(z)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$
Then since $x,y$ are continuous functions of $z$ (and $x\ne 0)$, it follows (assuming principal values) that $\text{arg}(z)$ is continuous on $B(1,1)$.

Note that for an arbitrary continuous function $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$, the function $\text{arg}(f(z))$ need not be continuous.

For example, if the image of $f$ contains an open ball centered at $0$, then for that function $f$, no choice of interval for $\text{arg}$ can make $\arg(f(z))$ continuous.

But for this problem, it's given that $f:\mathbb{C}\to C$ is such that the image of $f$ is contained in $B(1,1)$. Also, I'll assume the actual problem required $f$ to be continuous.

Thus, since $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}$, and $\text{arg}(z)$ is continuous on the image of $f$, it follows that $\text{arg}(f(z))$ is continuous.

Comment: I am sorry I have no idea what this means, could you elaborate further please?

Comment: I edited in an explanation. If you draw a picture of $B(1,1)$, it should become clear.

Comment: ok I think I get it alittle more, but why is the principle value strictly in between  $(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$??

Comment: Note: By convention, for $z\in C$, with $z\ne 0$, the principal value of $\text{arg}(z)$ is the unique angle in the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$ between $z$ and the positive $x$-axis. But the open ball $B(1,1)$ lies strictly to the right of the $y$-axis, so the angles for $z\in B(1,1)$ are in the open interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: Why cant it be from $[0,2\pi]$ since $z$ is still inside $B(1,1) ?$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Principal_value

Comment: Generally, if $w$ is continuous, then $\arg w$ is continuous?

Comment: No, not necessarily, but in this case, the geometry clinches it. For example, the principal value of $\text{arg}(z)$ is not continuous in $B(0,1)$ (think about what happens when you cross from one side to the other of the negative $x$-axis).

Comment: The choice of interval for $\arg{z}$ is arbitrary. It _could_ be taken as, say, $[0,2\pi)$, but in the context of this problem, it's clear that the intended interval is the standard one for principal value (as in the wiki link).

Answer (score 1):

Your ball $B(1,1)$ has centre at $(1,0)\equiv 1+0i$ with radius $1$. Let $z$ be a complex number inside that ball, i.e. in a neighbourhood of $1+0i$. So $x=\Re(z)>0$ and you can use simple trig to calculate its argument to get $\arg(x+iy)=\tan^{-1}(y/x)$. If we define our principle branch to be $[-\pi/2,3\pi/2)$, then since $x>0$ the argument is always going to be within the range $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, so yes the argument is continuous. There are no discontinuities.

However, I think this depends on how you choose your principle branch. E.g. you could choose it to be $[-\pi/2,3\pi/2)$ as I have above, or you could choose it to be $[0,2\pi)$ in which case you would get discontinuities. How is the principle branch defined?

Not sure about $\arg(f(z))$ though. What happens if $f$ is discontinuous?

Comment: Ok that was strange, the previous post got deleted, and so I will ask here. Why do we choose some principle argument? For instance $1+i$ the complex number has the argument $\pi/4$ but how can we determine its interval?

Comment: I didn't delete it I just updated it because I got the definition of the ball wrong - $B(z,r)$ is a ball, centre $z$, radius $r$, and not centre $z+ir$ as I stupidly wrote first. It's been a while since I've played ball !

Comment: Regarding the principle branch: take the complex number $z=1+i$, which has argument $\pi/2$. Or does it? Surely any argument of the form $\pi/2+2\pi k$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ is a perfectly fine candidate since $e^{i(\pi/2+2\pi k)}=e^{i\pi/2}$. So you see, if you don't choose a *principal branch* then a single complex number can have many arguments. And that is what we call "not well-defined." Without choosing a principle branch, the argument function is a multi-valued function, and they are complicated to work with. To bring everything back down to Earth we usually choose a principle branch.